# Moving from a register to a variable x86

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, irvine32

I have an array containing sbytes which get get added to each other using the

> edx

and

> ebp

registers.

The code works fine, except now I am trying to move

> ebp

to a variable called total_sum which would hold SWORDs. However, I am not sure how to do that.

The error I'm getting is

> error A2022: instruction operands must be the same siz

which I understand to mean that the formats I am trying to convert between are different.

Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Here is the relevant code:

```
mov esi, OFFSET array
mov ecx, LENGTHOF array
mov total_sum, 0
mov ebp,0

L1:
movsx edx, byte ptr [esi]
add ebp, edx
inc esi
loop L1

mov eax, ebp
call WriteInt
call Crlf

mov [total_sum], ebp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mov byte ptr [total_sum], ebp
```

The variable is declared as a byte, the register is 4 bytes. The assembler is not sure what do you mean - truncate the register, or use four bytes that start at label total_sum.

Comment: Is that all that has to be done? I tried that and the issue remained.

Comment: Then declare the variable as DWORD, and remove the "byte ptr".

Comment: Is there any way to keep it as an SWORD?

Comment: @HBoll: `mov [total_sum], bp` is how you do a 16-bit store.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for that.

Comment: I wonder what this answer actually do, it shouldn't compile in MASM/TASM? AFAIK it's not possible to store 8b of `ebp` directly (in 32b mode), you have to move it to some other register, which has 8b part accessible, like `al/bl/cl/dl`. For `SWORD` as stated in question the situation is better, lower 16b of `ebp` can be accessed through `bp`. ... If that answer would somehow compile, I would be afraid it will store 4 bytes, ie. overwrites memory one would not expect from the "byte ptr" wording.